# How to UnitTest a custom Exeption with SerializationInfo correctly?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

I have my own Exception and because of SonarQube I implemented all 4 base constructures of System.Exception:

```
[Serializable]
public class DatabaseVersionNotReadableException : Exception
{
    private static readonly string Text = "Database Version not found or not readable: {0}";
    
    public DatabaseVersionNotReadableException()
    {
        
    }
    
    public DatabaseVersionNotReadableException(string version)
        : base(String.Format(Text, version))
    {

    }
    
    public DatabaseVersionNotReadableException(string version, Exception exception) : base(String.Format(Text, version), exception)
    {
        
    }
    
    protected DatabaseVersionNotReadableException(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
        
    }
}
```

To unit test the first 3 const was very easy, but I have no idea how to setup a SerializationInfo  and / or StreamingContext correctly to even get a simple test together. I tried find it out with google, but there seem to be no information about it.

How to unit test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That API is used by `BinaryFormatter` for custom deserialization; so: serialize and deserialize your exception with `BinaryFormatter`.

Except, don't; `BinaryFormatter` is obsolete, deprecated and dangerous. IMO, unless you absolutely need that capability (for example, you're using "remoting" in .NET Framework and anticipate this exception going over the remoted boundary): just don't include it, and don't add `[Serializable]`.